# Get tree view of / Walk through an xml file (.h5) file until the final branches with h5py

Tags: python, xml, treeview, h5py

I want to walk through the item of a `.h5` file in python. When implementing the code found in [this github issue](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/406), I can only see the first 2 levels of depth of the tree, whereas with the matlab function `h5disp()`, it seems to be possible to go until the final branches of the xml tree. Is there a way to have the same kind of output with h5py?
The `.h5` data was taken from [there](http://www.mridata.org/list?project=Stanford%20Undersampled%203D%20FSE%20Knees,%20Uniform%20vs%20Variable%20Density%20Poisson%20Disk) (MRI Data)

Here is a python code

```
import h5py
from h5py import File

path_and_file = "fd28ac5d-ed5a-462f-9064-0a5a13d76291.h5"
def print_attrs(name, obj):
    # Create indent
    shift = name.count('/') * '    '
    item_name = name.split("/")[-1]
    print(shift + item_name)
    try:
        for key, val in obj.attrs.items():
            print(shift + '    ' + f"{key}: {val}")
    except:
        pass

f = h5py.File(path_and_file,'r')
f.visititems(print_attrs)
```

with its corresponding output

```
dataset
    data
    rec_mean
    rec_std
    xml
```

Here is the Matlab function call

```
>> h5disp('fd28ac5d-ed5a-462f-9064-0a5a13d76291.h5')
```

with its corresponding output

```
HDF5 fd28ac5d-ed5a-462f-9064-0a5a13d76291.h5 
Group '/' 
    Group '/dataset' 
        Dataset 'data' 
            Size:  7996
            MaxSize:  Inf
            Datatype:   H5T_COMPOUND
                Member 'head':  H5T_COMPOUND
                    Member 'version':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'flags':  H5T_STD_U64LE (uint64)
                    Member 'measurement_uid':  H5T_STD_U32LE (uint32)
                    Member 'scan_counter':  H5T_STD_U32LE (uint32)
                    Member 'acquisition_time_stamp':  H5T_STD_U32LE (uint32)
                    Member 'physiology_time_stamp':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_STD_U32LE (uint32)
                    Member 'number_of_samples':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'available_channels':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'active_channels':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'channel_mask':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 16
                        Base Type:  H5T_STD_U64LE (uint64)
                    Member 'discard_pre':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'discard_post':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'center_sample':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'encoding_space_ref':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'trajectory_dimensions':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'sample_time_us':  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'position':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'read_dir':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'phase_dir':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'slice_dir':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'patient_table_position':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 3
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                    Member 'idx':  H5T_COMPOUND
                        Member 'kspace_encode_step_1':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'kspace_encode_step_2':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'average':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'slice':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'contrast':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'phase':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'repetition':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'set':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'segment':  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                        Member 'user':  H5T_ARRAY
                            Size: 8
                            Base Type:  H5T_STD_U16LE (uint16)
                    Member 'user_int':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 8
                        Base Type:  H5T_STD_I32LE (int32)
                    Member 'user_float':  H5T_ARRAY
                        Size: 8
                        Base Type:  H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                Member 'traj':  H5T_VLEN
                    Base Type: H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
                Member 'data':  H5T_VLEN
                    Base Type: H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
            ChunkSize:  1
            Filters:  none
        Dataset 'rec_mean' 
            Size:  8x1
            MaxSize:  8xInf
            Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
            ChunkSize:  8x1
            Filters:  none
            FillValue:  0.000000
        Dataset 'rec_std' 
            Size:  8x1
            MaxSize:  8xInf
            Datatype:   H5T_IEEE_F32LE (single)
            ChunkSize:  8x1
            Filters:  none
            FillValue:  0.000000
        Dataset 'xml' 
            Size:  1
            MaxSize:  1
            Datatype:   H5T_STRING
                String Length: variable
                Padding: H5T_STR_NULLTERM
                Character Set: H5T_CSET_ASCII
                Character Type: H5T_C_S1
            ChunkSize:  []
            Filters:  none
```

Comment: You are finding the same `datasets` as the MATLAB, but you aren't displaying any information about their contents. Start by displaying `shape` and `dtype`.